# Celery: How to create signature for a class-based task?

Tags: python, python-3.x, celery

Python 3.7, Celery 4.3

I have a class-based task registered:

```py
class TaskA(celery_app.Task):
    name = 'task_a'

    def run(self, my_param):
       pass

celery_app.tasks.register(TaskA())
```

I want to create a chain of tasks, where TaskA should be one of the links.

Here's how I do it:

```py
my_param = "some value"

result = celery.chain(
    TaskA.s(my_param),
    # ...
)()
```

And I get the error:

```
TypeError: s() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace thic code:

```
my_param = "some value"

result = celery.chain(
    TaskA.s(my_param),
    # ...
)()
```

with:

```
my_param = "some value"

task_ = TaskA() # <------
result = celery.chain(
    task_.s(my_param),
    # ...
)()
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Looks like `signature()` and `s()` functions should be called on instance of the task, not on the task class.